# Button not appear on GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, button

I am struggling why the button does not appear on GUI when I run it. I am creating the Calculator by using Java. I am testing the two buttons ( del button and clr button) before going further since I want to double check if my current code run well.

However, when I tried it, my buttons didn't appear. I do not know where I did wrong. Could you take a look at my code and assist me what is the problem?

```
package phan;

/**
 *
 * @author bemua
 */
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

        
public class Calculator implements ActionListener {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    JFrame frame;
    JTextField textField;
    JButton[] numberButtons = new JButton[10];
    JButton[] functionButtons = new JButton[9];
    JButton addButton, subButton, mulButton, divButton;
    JButton decButton, equButton, delButton, clrButton;
    JPanel panel;
    
    Font myFont = new Font("Ink Free", Font.BOLD, 30);
    
    double num1 = 0, num2 = 0, result = 0;
    char operator;
    Calculator(){
        // create frame
        frame = new JFrame("CALCULATOR");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(420, 550);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.pack();
        
        
        // create text field
        
         textField = new JTextField();
         textField.setBounds(50,25,300,50); //setBounds.(x,y,width, height
        textField.setFont(myFont);
        textField.setEditable(true);
        
        
        // create button
        addButton = new JButton("+");
        subButton = new JButton("-");
        mulButton = new JButton("*");
        divButton = new JButton("/");
        decButton = new JButton(".");
        equButton = new JButton("=");
        delButton = new JButton("Delete");
        clrButton = new JButton("Clear");
        
        // array contains function
        
        functionButtons[0] = addButton;
        functionButtons[1] = subButton;
        functionButtons[2] = mulButton;
        functionButtons[3] = divButton;
        functionButtons[4] = decButton;
        functionButtons[5] = equButton;
        functionButtons[6] = delButton;
        functionButtons[7] = clrButton;
        
        for ( int i = 0; i < 9;i++) {
            functionButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
            functionButtons[i].setFont(myFont);
            functionButtons[i].setFocusable(false);
        }
         for ( int i = 0; i < 10 ;i++) {
             numberButtons[i] = new JButton(String.valueOf(i));
             numberButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
             numberButtons[i].setFont(myFont);
             numberButtons[i].setFocusable(false);
             
         }
        
         delButton.setBounds(50,430,145,50);
         clrButton.setBounds(50,430,145,50);
         
         frame.add(delButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
         frame.add(clrButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
         frame.add(textField);
         frame.setVisible(true);
         
        
        
        
        
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculator calc = new Calculator();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       
    }
    
}
```

Here is the error after I run the code:

**run**:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    
       at phan.Calculator.<init>(Calculator.java:69)
       at phan.Calculator.main(Calculator.java:95)
```

Comment: `functionButtons[8]` is `null`.

Comment: You need an object to access its properties or methods. Now if you see you have initialized the array named `functionButtons`. Now you have an object of array of class `JButton` but all the slots are referring to null objects. Now in your constructor you initialize the slots of the array to various buttons, but only 0 to 7 slots, you still have slot 8 and 9 referring to null.  Now let us see the problem. You have a for loop looping from 0 to 9 and as soon as the loop iteration happens for `i = 8` and you try to invoke method on the `functionButtons[8]` you get NullPointerException.